# pandas select row without knowing number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an imported dataframe of which i do not know the number of columns or name of the columns (as this varies)

in this case it is I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
a = {'Attempts': [10, 15, 5, 25, 30], '2nd Attempts': [10, 12, 15, 14, 0],
 '3rd Attempts': [10, 10, 9, 11, 10]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
```

How would I go about only selecting only the rows which contain the number 10. So in this case I would return row 1, 2 and 5 (or 0, 1 and 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` created by compare all values in `DataFrame` with `10` and then add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for return at least one `True`:

```
print (a == 10)
  2nd Attempts 3rd Attempts Attempts
0         True         True     True
1        False         True    False
2        False        False    False
3        False        False    False
4        False         True    False

mask = (a == 10).any(axis=1)
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print (a[mask])
   2nd Attempts  3rd Attempts  Attempts
0            10            10        10
1            12            10        15
4             0            10        30
```

---

```
a = {'Attempts': ['a', 'ten', 'b', 'd', 'ten'], '2nd Attempts': [10, 12, 15, 14, 0],
 '3rd Attempts': [10, 10, 9, 11, 10]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
   2nd Attempts  3rd Attempts Attempts
0            10            10        a
1            12            10      ten
2            15             9        b
3            14            11        d
4             0            10      ten

mask = (a.values == 'ten').any(1)
print (mask)
[False  True False False  True]

print (a[mask])
   2nd Attempts  3rd Attempts Attempts
1            12            10      ten
4             0            10      ten
```

Comment: Great that works really well. Could that work with words as well? for instance if all the numbers were written out, i was trying to select 'ten'?

Comment: sure, it can works with `string` nice, but if some numeric columns only is necessary cast to `str` by `mask = (a.astype(str) == 'ten').any(axis=1)`

Comment: Or compare numpy array by `mask = (a.values == 'ten').any(axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks so much. Works really well